# Timespan Year and Month in decimal c#

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp

I have two `decimal` values

```
3.10m = 3 years 10 months 
 2.8m = 2 years  8 months.
```

I am trying to `sum` these values the result is `5.9` which is *incorrect*.

The *expected* result should be

```
6.6m = 6 years 6 months
```

Can any one pls *suggest* how can we achieve this using `TimeSpan` or any other way in C# . Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why did you want to use `decimal` response for DateTime?

Comment: How do you *distinguish* between `3.1` (`3` years `1` month) and `3.10` (`3` years `10` months)?

Comment: The identity 3.10 = 3 years 10 month seems wrong to me. According to that logic 3.12 would be 3 years 12 month or 4 years.

Comment: *how can we achieve this using TimeSpan or any other way in C#?* Using `TimeSpan` you can just do `TimeSpan total = span1 + span2;` (where `span1` and `span2` are also of type `TimeSpan`).

Comment: @MatthewWatson: That doesn't help when you can't represent months or years in `TimeSpan` though.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: `decimal` makes it *possible* to distinguish between 3.1 and 3.10, but it would still be a horrible representation.

Comment: I would avoid using months altogether - the total number of days represented by the months will differ depending on the start date, since months have different lengths. And then when you add them together, things get even worse...

Comment: @Matthew Watson: yes, you are quite right: it's a problem to add a month to, say, `30 Jan 2018` (is it `28 Feb 2018`? And what if we subtract `1` month back?); however, it's often a business request (should be shipped *within a month* etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not do this! `decimal` are not for `year.month`. Technically you can solve the problem and *distinguish* `3.1m` and `3.10m` (`decimal.GetBits` helps out); here is the code for the *academic use* only:

```
private static decimal EerieArithmetics(decimal d1, decimal d2) {
  int y1 = (int)d1;
  int m1 = (int)((d1 % 1m) * ((((decimal.GetBits(d1)[3] >> 16) & 31) == 2) ? 100m : 10m));

  int y2 = (int)d2;
  int m2 = (int)((d2 % 1m) * ((((decimal.GetBits(d2)[3] >> 16) & 31) == 2) ? 100m : 10m));

  int y = y1 + y2 + (m1 + m2) / 12;
  int m = (m1 + m2) % 12;

  return y + (m == 10 ? 0.10m : m > 10 ? m / 100.00m : m / 10.0m);
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Tuple<decimal, decimal>[] tests = new Tuple<decimal, decimal>[] {
  Tuple.Create(3.10m,  2.8m),
  Tuple.Create( 3.1m,  2.8m),
  Tuple.Create( 3.0m,  2.8m),
  Tuple.Create( 3.0m,  2.0m),
  Tuple.Create(   3m,    2m),
  Tuple.Create( 3.8m,  2.4m),
  Tuple.Create(3.10m, 3.10m),
  Tuple.Create( 2.8m,  2.2m),
  Tuple.Create(2.11m,  2.2m),
};

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => 
     $"{test.Item1,5} + {test.Item2,5} == {EerieArithmetics(test.Item1, test.Item2),5}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 3.10 +   2.8 ==   6.6
  3.1 +   2.8 ==   5.9
  3.0 +   2.8 ==   5.8
  3.0 +   2.0 ==     5
    3 +     2 ==     5
  3.8 +   2.4 ==     6
 3.10 +  3.10 ==   7.8
  2.8 +   2.2 ==  4.10
 2.11 +   2.2 ==   5.1
```

I hope, I *scared you out* of such use of `decimal`. As a *quick and dirty* patch (if you can't use any library but standard one) you can try `DateTime` class:

```
 DateTime d1 = new DateTime(3, 10, 1); // 1 Oct 3 AD
 DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2, 8, 1);  // 1 Aug 2 AD

 DateTime result = d1
   .AddYears(d2.Year)
   .AddMonths(d2.Month);               // 1 Jun 6 AD

 // 6.6
 Console.Write($"{result.Year}.{result.Month}");
```

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I'd avoid using decimals like that to represent year/month values. As noted in comments, you won't be able to *easily* distinguish between 1 month and 10 months... while `decimal` *can* represent the difference between 3.1 and 3.10, it would be a very weird usage. Just keep the two values in separate integers.

Next, you can't do arithmetic like this with `TimeSpan`. A `TimeSpan` just stores "a number of ticks" - it doesn't handle ideas like "1 month" or "1 year" because those don't represent fixed numbers of ticks.

I'd recommend using my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) library instead. You'd represent these values as `Period` objects. You still wouldn't be able to add years and months together directly - `Period` doesn't assume a Gregorian calendar system, and arithmetic like this just doesn't work for some non-Gregorian calendars, especially those which vary the number of months based on the year. However, you could easily write your own `Period` normalization method:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Period p1 = new PeriodBuilder { Years = 3, Months = 10 }.Build();
        Period p2 = new PeriodBuilder { Years = 5, Months = -12 }.Build();
        Period sum = p1 + p2;
        Period normalized = NormalizeYearsAndMonths(sum);
        Console.WriteLine($"{normalized.Years} years; {normalized.Months} months");
    }

    static Period NormalizeYearsAndMonths(Period period)
    {
        // TODO: Handle negative years and months however you want.
        int years = period.Years;
        int months = period.Months;
        years += months / 12;
        months = months % 12;
        var builder = period.ToBuilder();
        builder.Years = years;
        builder.Months = months;
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Now of course you *could* just keep everything in two integers instead - the benefit of using a `Period` is that you can then easily add it to a `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` etc. You could even do that without normalizing to start with, if you want.